# Array dinámico PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array: `$frutas = array("Peras", "Mangos", "Manzanas");`

Y tengo este otro array: `$valor = array("1200", "3500", "7000");`

¿Cómo puedo conseguir fusionar los dos arrays de tal manera que quede así:

`$frutas = array("Peras" => 1200, "Mangos" => 3500, "Manzanas" => 7000);` ?

Itenté de la siguiente forma, pero no funcionó:

```
$frutasTotal = array($frutas => $valor);
```

Luego hice un for que iterara sobre **$frutas**, pero sólo me imprimió el último ítem...

```
for($i=0; $i < count($frutas); $i++){

     $frutasTotal = array($frutas[$i] => $valor[$i]); //Output: "Manzana" => "7000"

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ibas mal encaminado, pero en tu caso, al declarar `$frutas_total` dentro del `foreach`, estás provocando que la variable contenga un nuevo `array` en cada iteración del bucle, machacando lo que la variable tuviese de antes. Por eso tan solo conseguías obtener la última parejas de `$frutas => $valor`.

**PHP**

```
$frutas = array("Peras", "Mangos", "Manzanas");
$valor = array("1200", "3500", "7000");
$frutas_valor = array();

for($i=0; $i < count($frutas); $i++){
    $frutas_valor[$frutas[$i]] = $valor[$i];
}

print_r($frutas_valor);
```

**Salida por pantalla:**

```
Array ( [Peras] => 1200 [Mangos] => 3500 [Manzanas] => 7000 )
```

De esta manera, declaras e inicializas el `array` fuera del bucle y lo vas llenando correctamente en el interior del `foreach`.

Answer (score 4):

usando [`array_combine ( $claves, $valores )`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php)

```
<?php 
$frutas = array("Peras", "Mangos", "Manzanas");
$valor = array("1200", "3500", "7000");
$frutas_valor = array_combine( $frutas, $valor );
print_r ( $frutas_valor );
```

---

```
Array
(
    [Peras] => 1200
    [Mangos] => 3500
    [Manzanas] => 7000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como aportación quisiera señalar que si por algún motivo **hay valores repetidos en el array `$frutas`** va a ser necesario crear un array anidado con índices numéricos, o de lo contrario, tanto `array_combine` como un bucle simple, dejarán solamente una clave.

Supongamos este ejemplo, donde `Peras` estaría dos veces en el array:

```
$frutas = array("Peras", "Peras", "Manzanas");
$valor = array("1200", "3500", "7000");
$frutas_valor = array();
```

La asociación estricta entre ambos arrays tendría que hacerse así:

```
foreach ($frutas as $k=>$v){
    $frutas_valor[]=array ($v=>$valor[$k]);
}
```

Quedando los datos así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Peras] => 1200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Peras] => 3500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Manzanas] => 7000
        )

)
```

La lectura se haría de este modo:

```
foreach ($frutas_valor as $item){
    foreach ($item as $k=>$v){
        echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Peras: 1200
Peras: 3500
Manzanas: 7000
```

Creo que conviene tomarlo en cuenta, para escenarios en los que podría haber valores duplicados.

El mismo código serviría para arrays dispares, haciendo una pequeña modificación dentro del bucle.